# Android Layout, limiting the width of a RelativeLayout child

Tags: android, android-layout, chat, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make an Android platform chat application with bubbles for the chat page.

I succeeded in making bubble for the right side of conversation by using a LinearLayout, and when the Message TextView has multiple lines, it will wrap without pushing the Status TextView out of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bubble_status"
            android:textColor="#5D5958"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/bubble_time"
            android:textColor="#5D5958"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_tosca"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="@string/bubble_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But a different thing occurs when I build the left side of the conversation.
First, I'm using the same LinearLayout, but just switch sides and gravity from right to left, and it didn't work.
The Message TextView will push the status out of the screen.
So I've changed it by using a RelativeLayout.
This works only for short text as the TextView didn't wrap, but when I put a long text inside it will wrap and push the status TextView out of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_odd_grey"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:text="@string/bubble_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bubble"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bubble"
        android:text="@string/bubble_time"
        android:textColor="#5D5958"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: remove this attribute `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: @kaushik i dont think thats the problem, I'm putting the android:singleLine='true' so it doesnt wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after discussing with my friends, I've found my answers. So here is the expected code looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_odd_grey"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:text="@string/bubble_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fakeLayout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bubble"
        android:text="@string/bubble_time"
        android:textColor="#5D5958"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fakeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bubble2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_odd_grey"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:text="@string/bubble_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bubble"
        android:text="@string/bubble_time"
        android:textColor="#5D5958"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot :
[image]

Comment: it gives "Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout"
I think because you're calling @id/bubble2 inside @id/bubble and vice versa

Comment: wow, you're right.. i think its because i write android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bubble2" instead of "@+id/bubble2"

but this works on long text message, but if its small text message it doesnt wrap smaller

Comment: do you want the right bubble to have the top part part aligned with the top part of the left bubble?